# Writing Errors to File in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, error-logging

I want to write errors to a file in Postgresql, so whenever error occurs in a function it writes to a file, so I have captured the error and I pass on the error to another function and the return of that function is written to a file. Below is a sample function,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(TEXT)
RETURNS VOID
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare STATEMENT TEXT;
declare sql_code TEXT;
BEGIN

BEGIN
EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || $1;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
sql_code := SQLERRM;
     STATEMENT := 'COPY (select * from test1('''||sql_code||''')) to ''/tmp/errors.txt''';
     EXECUTE STATEMENT;
RETURN;
END;
RAISE NOTICE 'Dropped table successfully %', $1;
RETURN;
END;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1(TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
STRICT
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare error TEXT;
BEGIN
error :=  $1;
RETURN STATEMENT;
END;
$$;
```

This thing works fine but I want to know if there is any good way to capture the error and log it to a file ? Please suggest.

Comment: Have you read [Error Reporting and logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-logging.html)?

Comment: @fbynite : yes, but I am not allowed to enable logging collector on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Changing logging levels would be preferable though there may be good reasons to prevent this.

Failing that you could write a secondary logging routine in, say, pl/perlu, or pl/python, which could write to a file.  Just be careful that you don't overwrite your data files O.o.....